# How to push data to an existing index(Elastic Search) from Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

```
elasticsearch {
                hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
                index => "logmessages"
                document_type => "message"
       }
```

I want to create an Index with certain mappings in Elasticsearch and then point Logstash to that Index to store data. How do I do it? It seems to work fine when Logstash pushes data to a non-existing Index.

Comment: Maybe with the template option (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-template)?

Comment: Anything in the logstash or elasticsearch logs?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create an index with required mappings then pass index name as follows:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elastic_search_server_ip:port"] #localhost:9200
    action => "index"
    index => "your_existing_index_name"}

# How to create index with mappings 
index_mapping = {
    "settings": {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "number_of_replicas": 0
        },

    'mappings': {'properties': {
        'id': {'type': 'long'},
        "location": {
                "type": "geo_point"
                } 
    }}}
resp = es.indices.create(index = "test", body = index_mapping, ignore = 400)
```

Note: Your index should contain all the columns/fields.